# Editing a module seems to have no effect

Tags: magento, debugging, caching, plugins, magento-1.9

I am using a module which calculates the shipping method based on item weight. The module appears to install but if I make an edit to the main class, nothing seems to be reflected on the front end.

The main class extends the Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract see below:

```
<?php  
class Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping_Model_Carrier_Advancedshipping     
extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{   

    protected $_code = 'advancedshipping';
```

The config.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <advancedshipping>
        <class>Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping_Helper</class>
      </advancedshipping>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <advancedshipping>
        <class>Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping_Block</class>
      </advancedshipping>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <advancedshipping>
        <class>Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>advancedshipping_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </advancedshipping>
      <advancedshipping_mysql4>
        <class>Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>        
              <matrix>
                <table>advancedshipping_matrix</table>
              </matrix>
        </entities>
      </advancedshipping_mysql4>
            <shipping>
                <rewrite>
                    <shipping>Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping_Model_Shipping_Shipping</shipping>
                </rewrite>
            </shipping>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <advancedshipping_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </advancedshipping_setup>
      <advancedshipping_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </advancedshipping_write>
      <advancedshipping_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </advancedshipping_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <advancedshipping>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping</module>
          <frontName>advancedshipping</frontName>
        </args>
      </advancedshipping>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <advancedshipping module="advancedshipping">
        <title>Advancedshipping</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <matrix module="advancedshipping">
            <title>Manage Matrix</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>advancedshipping/adminhtml_matrix</action>
          </matrix>
          <import module="advancedshipping">
            <title>Import from CSV</title>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <action>advancedshipping/adminhtml_matrix/import</action>
          </import>
          <settings>
            <title>Manage Settings</title>
            <sort_order>999</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/lm_advancedshipping</action>
          </settings>
        </children>
      </advancedshipping>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <advancedshipping translate="title" module="advancedshipping">
              <title>Advancedshipping</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
                  <matrix translate="title">
                    <title>Manage Matrix</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                  </matrix>
                  <import translate="title">
                    <title>Import from CSV</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                  </import>
                  <settings translate="title">
                    <title>Manage Settings</title>
                    <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                  </settings>
              </children>
            </advancedshipping>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <advancedshipping>
          <file>advancedshipping.xml</file>
        </advancedshipping>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>    
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <advancedshipping>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>advancedshipping/carrier_advancedshipping</model>
                <name>Advanced Shipping</name>
                <title>Laurensmedia</title>
                <description>Laurensmedia Advanced Shipping description</description>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            </advancedshipping>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

I have tried the following:

- Clearing the Magneto cache
- Manually deleting the contents of /var/cache/
- Copying all of the other modules to ../disabled/ (Effectively
        disabling them)

None of the above seems to have worked. Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why when I edit the main class file nothing happens? Even if I deliberately break the file (i.e - delete half the code) I don't even see any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a `<rewrite>` declared for `Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping_Model_Carrier_Advancedshipping` in the config.

That would explain why it's not being picked up, since it appears to want to rewrite a standard Magento class.

If it's not intended as a rewrite, how is that class being called?

Comment: Thanks for your response.I can see one <rewrite> in the config for Laurensmedia_Advancedshipping_Model_Shipping_Shipping. Do you think this is incorrect?  I have very little expereice with Magento. Could suggest what I need to add or edit to config.xml?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about the internals of the module. Try and find references to that particular class, or calls using its alias in `Mage::getModel`. Once you know how the module wants to use the class, you can more easily determine why it is not being instantiated. You may want to try contacting the developer to see if they can give you more information - it's possible it's just a config that needs to be enabled in the admin.

Comment: Would you be interested in doing some paid freelance work to solve this for me?